# Maven Project class file not being found by eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, invocationtargetexception

I have couple of maven projects let's say A & B. I have mvm installed them both before loading them inside eclipse.

One of the class in project A runs a class from project B. This class is trying to create a instance of a another class in B using the newInstance method.

```
Class clazz = Class.forName(className);
Constructor construct = clazz.getConstructor(new Class[] { String.class, ThreadFactory.class });
ResultClassFromB api = (ResultClassFromB) construct.newInstance(new Object[] {file, threadFactory });
```

I get InvocationTargetException for above code. On the surface, I understand eclipse can't find class file for ResultClassFromB. I've tried adding the parent folder of ResultClassFromB in the class path of project A but I still see the issue. How do I get past this?

info: file is mostly with comments.

Comment: please post the stacktrace, and the relevant part in the pom.xml for project A where project B is indicated as a dependency.

Comment: Do you have dependencies added to the project from A to B or vice versa depending on the class.